# Convert JS logic into FTL

Tags: javascript, freemarker

i have a JS code which i want to convert on FTL so that users couldnt view the logic behind it. Is this possible?

I'm thiking of using <#if> and <#assign> for the logic but dont know how to start though.
find any other resources and looks like the Freemarker documentation is painful.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ref = document.referrer,
        currentPageURL = document.URL,
        expectedURL = "http://127.0.0.1";

    function getUrlVars(href)
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    var googleURL = ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?google\.com(\/|$)/i);
    if ((googleURL && (currentPageURL == expectedURL)) {
        //do stuff.
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `getUrlVars` doesn't seem to be used anywhere but if you need requests parameters you can get them with `${RequestParameters['test']}`, The referrer and current url are not available so you need to send them from the backend code to the template engine. then that condition is just a plain `<#if $referrerFromJava?matches("^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?google\.com(\/|$)">`. But if you move all this to checking to the server, just do in in the backend code and send a variable to ftl, something like `${isFromGoogle}`